# Rails and Pagy pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

How to set the maximum number of items that can be downloaded.

I set:

```
require 'pagy/extras/items'
Pagy::VARS[:max_items] = 50
```

in config/initializers/pagy.rb.

Nevertheless, if I enter the address localhost:3000/cars?items=1000, I get 1000 results.
And I expected 50.

How to limit the maximum number of elements that can be retrieved?

Pagy version 3.13
Rails version 6.1.3

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you set it in the `config/initializers/pagy.rb`, it will not load instantly and so, it runs with old configs, I don't know why, I doubt the cache engine.

So you can set it in the controller, example with mine app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    Pagy::VARS[:max_items] = 50 # Set the value you want!
    @pagy, @records = pagy(Car.all)
  end
end
```

It will work fine, limit the max items to 50!

Comment: the `Pagy::VARS[:max_items]` is a global configuration that should not be set in an action, because it wills stick for all the instances. If you want to limit the config to the action you should simply add it to the statement `@pagy, @records = pagy(Car.all, max_items: 50), or leave it in the initializer as the global default.

Comment: Not `all the instance`, just the `pages#home`. The good way maybe is ENV variable, then call and assign it!